# R: XGBoost and Feature Hashing. MError keeps increasing

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a multiclassification problem with just over 500 classes. The data is restaurant menu related and my goal is to classify an item based off the item name and the category it belongs to. I'm using the FeatureHashing library in R to hash out the item name and category fields. Then using XGBoost as my model. For some reason though the train error increases with every iteration. The dataset is very large... > 2 million rows. The weird thing is when I worked in Azure ML and did the same type of feature hashing and used a random forest model I was able to achieve around 80% accuracy on the training set. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. Here is some example code

```
## libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(FeatureHashing)
library(xgboost)

## sample data
df <- data.frame(
      item_name=c('jose cuervo', 'chicken with shrimp', 'lasagna',
            'oreos', 'chicken marsala', 'beef stew'),
      category=c('adult beverage', 'chicken dish', 'pasta',
         'dessert', 'chicken dish', 'soup'),
       target=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4)
)

## hashing function
f <- ~ category + split(item_name, delim=" ")

## hash features
hashed.mat <- hashed.model.matrix(f, df, hash.size=2^6)

## define some model parameters
num.class <- df$target %>% unique() %>% length()
target <- df$target

## xgboost paramters
xgb.params <- list(booster='gbtree',
                   objective='multi:softmax',
                   num_class=num.class,
                   eta=0.3,
                   gamma=0,
                   max_depth=6,
                   min_child_weight=1,
                   subsample=1,
                   colsample_bytree=1)

## fit model
xgb.fit <- xgboost(hashed.mat, target, params=xgb.params, nrounds=10,
               verbose=1, print_every_n = 1)
```

[image: here is what the error is doing]

Comment: eh , I just re-read your question ... below answer is no good, but I'll leave it up for posterity.

Comment: I would set `eval_metric="mlogloss"` in your training, its a little smoother and should be decreasing, helps you see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what is happening...**

When you train a very small dataset like you are in the sample ( 6 rows )

The parameter `min_child_weight=1` is preventing splitting from occurring -- so you have no model training.

set `min_child_weight=0` , then train ...

you should see this ( this is your data and your code with `min_child_weight=0` )...

```
> xgb.fit <- xgboost(hashed.mat, target, params=xgb.params, nrounds=12,
+                    verbose=1, print_every_n = 1)
[1] train-merror:0.000000 
[2] train-merror:0.000000 
[3] train-merror:0.000000 
[4] train-merror:0.000000 
[5] train-merror:0.000000 
[6] train-merror:0.000000 
[7] train-merror:0.000000 
[8] train-merror:0.000000 
[9] train-merror:0.000000 
[10]    train-merror:0.000000 
[11]    train-merror:0.000000 
[12]    train-merror:0.000000
```

**To observe what happened do this, this shows you the training :**

```
> xgb.model.dt.tree(model = xgb.fit)
     Tree Node   ID Feature         Split  Yes   No Missing     Quality     Cover
  1:    0    0  0-0       5 -9.536743e-07  0-1  0-2     0-1  0.85576522 1.9200001
  2:    0    1  0-1    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA> -0.03846154 1.6000001
  3:    0    2  0-2    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA>  0.06060606 0.3200000
  4:    1    0  1-0       4 -9.536743e-07  1-1  1-2     1-1  1.62249923 1.9200001
  5:    1    1  1-1    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA> -0.03508772 1.2800001
 ---                                                                             
176:   58    1 58-1    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA> -0.03234537 1.2372975
177:   58    2 58-2    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA>  0.04115688 0.4767628
178:   59    0 59-0      10 -9.536743e-07 59-1 59-2    59-1  0.47927150 1.7140603
179:   59    1 59-1    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA> -0.03234537 1.2372975
180:   59    2 59-2    Leaf            NA <NA> <NA>    <NA>  0.04115688 0.4767628
```

.

***When you run the code without the constraining hyper-parameter , should overfit nicely!***

Comment: eh, looks like something else is happening if you are training a large multiclass --